# Error while synchronizing my model in mysqlWB

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Trying to upload my data with synchronization but I am getting this error.
Before I had an error with Unknown character set: DEFAULT 
I removed all default characters from code but still getting this error in code.

```
ERROR: Error 1115: Unknown character set: ''
SQL Code:
        ALTER TABLE `Leads`.`amocrm_leads`
        DROP COLUMN `idamocrm`,
        ADD COLUMN `Название сделки` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_bin' NOT NULL FIRST,
        ADD COLUMN `Компания` VARCHAR(255) NULL AFTER `Название сделки`,
        ADD COLUMN `Основной контакт` VARCHAR(255) NULL AFTER `Компания`,
        ADD COLUMN `Компания контакта` VARCHAR(255) NULL AFTER `Основной контакт`,
        ADD COLUMN `Ответственный` VARCHAR(255) NULL AFTER `Компания контакта`,
        ADD COLUMN `Этап сделки` VARCHAR(255) NULL AFTER `Ответственный`,
        ADD COLUMN `Воронка` VARCHAR(255) NULL AFTER `Этап сделки`,
        ADD COLUMN `Бюджет` VARCHAR(255) NULL AFTER `Воронка`,
        ADD COLUMN `Дата создания` VARCHAR(255) NULL AFTER `Бюджет`,
        ADD COLUMN `Кем создана` VARCHAR(255) NULL AFTER `Дата создания`,
        ADD COLUMN `Дата изменения` VARCHAR(255) NULL AFTER `Кем создана`,
```

Comment: Just remove the `,` at the end

Comment: Here is the demo when you remove the `,` from the end of the code: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1696a001ba4356c0be5b5db4ac9cf3b0

Comment: @VBokšić do I have to remove all , at the end

Comment: @VBokšić I uploaded a new answer with all my code that I have. and splited it into tow sections first is my amocrm table second is table_data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why did you changed this line of code:

```
ADD COLUMN `Компания` VARCHAR(255) NULL AFTER `Название сделки`,
```

to this:

```
ADD COLUMN `Компания` VARCHAR(255) NULL   `Компания`,
```

And you have done the same for more than one line...?? First line is ok second is not.
Is now all ok ?

Comment: Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1115: Unknown character set: ''
SQL Code:
        ALTER TABLE `Leads`.`amocrm_leads` 
        DROP COLUMN `idamocrm`,
        ADD COLUMN `Название сделки` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_bin' NOT NULL FIRST,
        ADD COLUMN `Компания` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `Название сделки`,
        ADD COLUMN `Основной контакт` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `Компания`,

Comment: This what I get after I changed everything back

Comment: Sorry but again - can not see your code and can not see your whole error. Delete your previous comment answer and enter again - the entire code and the entire error.

Answer (score 0):

This is the whole code that I am working with. after I execute it u can see the error about a coma

```
-- MySQL Workbench Synchronization
-- Generated: 2019-11-05 15:44
-- Model: New Model
-- Version: 1.0
-- Project: Name of the project
-- Author: Georgiy Fidarov

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';

ALTER TABLE `Leads`.`amocrm_leads` 
DROP COLUMN `idamocrm`,
ADD COLUMN `Название сделки` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_bin' NOT NULL FIRST,
ADD COLUMN `Компания` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `Название сделки`,
ADD COLUMN `Основной контакт` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `Компания`,
ADD COLUMN `Компания контакта` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `Основной контакт`,
ADD COLUMN `Ответственный` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `Компания контакта`,
ADD COLUMN `Этап сделки` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `Ответственный`,
ADD COLUMN `Воронка` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `Этап сделки`,
ADD COLUMN `Бюджет` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `Воронка`,
ADD COLUMN `Дата создания` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `Бюджет`,
ADD COLUMN `Кем создана` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `Дата создания`,
ADD COLUMN `Дата изменения` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `Кем создана`,
ADD COLUMN `Кем изменена` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `Дата изменения`,
ADD COLUMN `Теги сделки` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `Кем изменена`,
ADD COLUMN `Ближайшая задача` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `Теги сделки`,
ADD COLUMN `Дата закрытия` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `Ближайшая задача`,
ADD COLUMN `Передано` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `Дата закрытия`,
ADD COLUMN `Номер FM` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `Передано`,
ADD COLUMN `Доход` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `Номер FM`,
ADD COLUMN `Другое` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `Доход`,
ADD COLUMN `roistat` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `Другое`,
ADD COLUMN `Город` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `roistat`,
ADD COLUMN `Источник` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `Город`,
ADD COLUMN `utm_source` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `Источник`,
ADD COLUMN `utm_medium` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `utm_source`,
ADD COLUMN `utm_campaign` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `utm_medium`,
ADD COLUMN `utm_term` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `utm_campaign`,
ADD COLUMN `utm_content` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `utm_term`,
ADD COLUMN `Переход с сайта` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `utm_content`,
ADD COLUMN `Сайт` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `Переход с сайта`,
ADD COLUMN `f30` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `Сайт`,
ADD COLUMN `Ответственный врач` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `f30`,
ADD COLUMN `Должность` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `Ответственный врач`,
ADD COLUMN `Рабочий email` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `Должность`,
ADD COLUMN `Личный email` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `Рабочий email`,
ADD COLUMN `Другой email` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `Личный email`,
ADD COLUMN `mail_list` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `Другой email`,
ADD COLUMN `work_phone1` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET '' NULL  AFTER `mail_list`,
ADD COLUMN `work_phone2` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `work_phone1`,
ADD COLUMN `mobile_phone` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `work_phone2`,
ADD COLUMN `fax` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `mobile_phone`,
ADD COLUMN `home_phone` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `fax`,
ADD COLUMN `another_phone` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `home_phone`,
ADD COLUMN `Skype` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `another_phone`,
ADD COLUMN `ICQ` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `Skype`,
ADD COLUMN `Jabber` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `ICQ`,
ADD COLUMN `Google Talk` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `Jabber`,
ADD COLUMN `MSN` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `Google Talk`,
ADD COLUMN `Другой IM` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `MSN`,
ADD COLUMN `Пользовательское соглашение` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `Другой IM`,
ADD COLUMN `Примечание 1` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `Пользовательское соглашение`,
ADD COLUMN `Примечание 2` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `Примечание 1`,
ADD COLUMN `Примечание 3` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `Примечание 2`,
ADD COLUMN `Примечание 4` VARCHAR(255) COLLATE '' NULL  AFTER `Примечание 3`,
ADD COLUMN `Примечание 5` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `Примечание 4`,
ADD COLUMN `id` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `Примечание 5`,
ADD COLUMN `id_fm_telmatch` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `id`,
ADD COLUMN `temp_id` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `id_fm_telmatch`,
ADD COLUMN `id_fm_count` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `temp_id`,
ADD COLUMN `Источник_` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `id_fm_count`,
ADD COLUMN `ind_filemaker_clear` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `Источник_`,
ADD COLUMN `match_found` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `ind_filemaker_clear`,
ADD COLUMN `ch_cannotfind` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `match_found`,
ADD COLUMN `rea` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `ch_cannotfind`,
ADD COLUMN `relate_1` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `rea`,
DROP PRIMARY KEY,
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`Название сделки`);
```

```
ALTER TABLE `Leads`.`data_table` 
DROP COLUMN `iddata`,
ADD COLUMN `amo_id` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_bin' NOT NULL FIRST,
ADD COLUMN `E_Mail` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `amo_id`,
ADD COLUMN `E_Mail 2` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `E_Mail`,
ADD COLUMN `E_Mail сопр` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `E_Mail 2`,
ADD COLUMN `Email 2 сопр` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `E_Mail сопр`,
ADD COLUMN `fname` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `Email 2 сопр`,
ADD COLUMN `id` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `fname`,
ADD COLUMN `lname` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `id`,
ADD COLUMN `name_name` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_bin' NOT NULL AFTER `lname`,
ADD COLUMN `namefull` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `name_name`,
ADD COLUMN `phone_relate_1` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `namefull`,
ADD COLUMN `temp_id` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `phone_relate_1`,
ADD COLUMN `vnr` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `temp_id`,
ADD COLUMN `Анамнез нем` VARCHAR(1000) NULL  AFTER `vnr`,
ADD COLUMN `Анамнез рус` VARCHAR(1000) NULL  AFTER `Анамнез нем`,
ADD COLUMN `Возраст` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `Анамнез рус`,
ADD COLUMN `Дата рождения` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `Возраст`,
ADD COLUMN `Дата создания` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `Дата рождения`,
ADD COLUMN `Диагноз нем` VARCHAR(1000) NULL  AFTER `Дата создания`,
ADD COLUMN `Диагноз рус` VARCHAR(1000) NULL  AFTER `Диагноз нем`,
ADD COLUMN `Имя сопр` VARCHAR(1000) NULL  AFTER `Диагноз рус`,
ADD COLUMN `Комментарий` VARCHAR(1000) NULL  AFTER `Имя сопр`,
ADD COLUMN `МКБ10` VARCHAR(1000) NULL  AFTER `Комментарий`,
ADD COLUMN `Обращение нем` VARCHAR(1000) NULL  AFTER `МКБ10`,
ADD COLUMN `Обращение рус` VARCHAR(1000) NULL  AFTER `Обращение нем`,
ADD COLUMN `Сотрудник` VARCHAR(1000) NULL  AFTER `Обращение рус`,
ADD COLUMN `Список задач` VARCHAR(1000) NULL  AFTER `Сотрудник`,
ADD COLUMN `Телефон` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `Список задач`,
ADD COLUMN `Телефон 2` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `Телефон`,
ADD COLUMN `Телефон 2 сопр` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `Телефон 2`,
ADD COLUMN `Телефон 3` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `Телефон 2 сопр`,
ADD COLUMN `Телефон 3 сопр` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `Телефон 3`,
ADD COLUMN `Телефон сопр` VARCHAR(1000) NULL  AFTER `Телефон 3 сопр`,
ADD COLUMN `Требования нем` VARCHAR(1000) NULL  AFTER `Телефон сопр`,
ADD COLUMN `Требования рус` VARCHAR(1000) NULL  AFTER `Требования нем`,
ADD COLUMN `Фамилия сопр` VARCHAR(1000) NULL  AFTER `Требования рус`,
ADD COLUMN `data::Дата создания` VARCHAR(255) NULL  AFTER `Фамилия сопр`,
DROP PRIMARY KEY,
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`name_name`);


ALTER TABLE `Leads`.`amocrm_leads` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `name_name`
  FOREIGN KEY (`Название сделки`)
  REFERENCES `Leads`.`data_table` (`name_name`)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE `Leads`.`data_table` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `name_name`
  FOREIGN KEY ()
  REFERENCES `Leads`.`amocrm_leads` ()
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Comment: Fidarov ok ok, I know but there are a lots of problems here... So I do not know how to tell you all of them... So I ask you. Can we make it easy and say that there is 4 groups of code ? Because you have 4 ALTER table statements. ok ?

Comment: @VBokšić Okay rn i executed first alter and got error with other 3 everything is nice. 
The second table was synchronized all columns was created but there is no data in rows there is written NULL

Comment: @VBokšić with my first alter I am having this error about "

Comment: Ok, lets begin : 1. In 1st and 2nd ALTER TABLE stetement you have a line of code : `DROP PRIMARY KEY`. This is not good. Because before that you do not have a PRIMARY KEY. YOu can remove that...

Comment: Yes yes, because there are more than one errors. Step by step.

Comment: 2. In first ALTER TABLE you have one part of code that say `COLLATE ''`- this is what is also wrong. Fix it.

Comment: @VBokšić do I have to remove it only in first table or for all of them. I did that only with first one, Got the same error

Comment: Only in first table, now, you also have collate '' in the first ALTER TABLE statement which is also wrong...

Comment: Hello @Georgy Fidarov,  did you fix it ?

Comment: Can you thn mark my answer as corerct ? That would be of help to me.